# Android Location null on emulator but working fine on device

Tags: android, android-activity, geolocation

I have class to get my location after button press :

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;

public class MyLocation {
    // Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;
    AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void> mtask;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
       // context = MyApp.getContext();
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        //  timer1=new Timer();
        // timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        mtask= new GetLastLocation().execute();
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // timer1.cancel();
            mtask.cancel(true);
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mtask.cancel(true);
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    private Context mContext;
    public MyLocation(Context c) { this.mContext = c; }


    class GetLastLocation extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>
    {

        ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog.setMessage("Searching....");
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Context... params)
        {
            Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());



            // ...
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
                    lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

                    Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
                    if(gps_enabled)
                        gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                    if(network_enabled)
                        net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                    //if there are both values use the latest one
                    if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                        if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                            locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                        else
                            locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                        return;
                    }

                    if(gps_loc!=null){
                        locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                        return;
                    }
                    if(net_loc!=null){
                        locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                        return;
                    }
                    locationResult.gotLocation(null);
                }
            });
            // ...


            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }





    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

And I use it like that:

(in on create method):

```
myLocation = new MyLocation(MainActivity.this);
```

(in on click listener):

```
MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult(){
                    @Override
                    public void gotLocation(final Location location){
                        for(PhoneNumberContainer object: tel){
                            Log.v("lista",object.number);

                        }
                        if(location==null){ Log.v("lista1","przejebane");}
                        else {
                            Collections.sort(tel, new CustomComparator(location));
                        }
                        for(PhoneNumberContainer object: tel){
                            Log.v("lista1",object.number);

                        }
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        int res = ctx.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.CALL_PHONE");
                        if (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + tel.get(0).number));
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }
                };
                myLocation.getLocation(MainActivity.this, locationResult);
```

And my problem is when I test the code on device it works well, but when I test it on emulator I get `null` instead of location. Why is that so? And is it my luck that it's working on device (may break on the other one) or should it work in all cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some emulator has no gps 。if you want to develop with emulator . I suggest you use Genymotion